# How to remove automatically added custom style tag?

Tags: css

My WordPress head tag contain custom style tag for fonts which inserted automatically on all page. Which causes following AMP error,

> Only amp-boilerplate and amp-custom 'style' tags are allowed, and only in the document head.

How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the style tag was added by the flying font plugin. I have modified the file 'wp-content/plugins/flying-fonts/flying-fonts.php'

```
................
$style =
"<style>body{font-family:-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,'Segoe UI',Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,'Fira Sans','Droid Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important}code{font-family:Menlo,Consolas,Monaco,Liberation Mono,Lucida Console,monospace !important}</style>";
$style =''; // set the style as ''
$html = str_replace('</head>', $style . '</head>', $html);
.........
```

And i have added the style manually in non AMP page header.